# Spying on a function returned by another function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a mocked resource that is simply an object of functions, in this case only one. This function returns another function. The code looks like this:

```
var mockRevivhalResource = {
    tenantOptions: function tenantOptions() {
        return {
            post: function post() {
            }
        }
    }
};
var RevivhalResource = mockRevivhalResource;
```

I am able to spy on tenantOptions() with `spyOn(RevivhalResource, 'tenantOptions');` but I can't seem to spy on `post()` that `tenantOptions()` returns.

The only thing that doesn't throw an error is  `spyOn(RevivhalResource.tenantOptions(), 'post');` but I believe I am simply setting the spy on a new instance on the post function, but when the angular application calls `RevivhalResource.tenantOptions().post();` it's calling a new instance of post because if I have `console.log("test");` in the mocked post function the tests print out "test" even if I don't let the spy callThrough. But I could be wrong on that matter.

The controller code that is calling the resource is like this

```
$scope.fun = function fun() {
    RevivhalResource.tenantOptions().post(
        {...stuff...},
        function success(data) {...success handler...},
        function error(data) {...error handler...}
    )
};
```

with RevivhalResource being a angularjs provider like this

```
angular.module('revivhal').provider('RevivhalResource', [function () {
    ...init stuff...
    this.$get = function ($resource) {
        ...more init stuff...
        return {
            tenantOptions: function tenantOptions() {
                return $resource(...path..., {...data...}, 
                                 post: {method: "POST"});
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

And what I'm trying to do is using a spy to confirm that RevivhalResource.tenantOptions().post() has been called. I then need to make the spy call the success and error handlers to test that the handlers are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refactor your mock so its build out of spies that return other spies:

```
var postSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
var tenantOptionsSpy = jasmine.createSpy()
var mockRevivhalResource = {
    tenantOptions: tenantOptionsSpy.andReturn({post: postSpy})
};

mockRevivhalResource.tenantOptions().post()
expect(tenantOptionsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(postSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```